# While loop overwrites field

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, while-loop

I am trying to execute a loop that calculates a new field "DELTA", using values in the existing dataframe. My goal is to use the DELTA field to calculate the next row of the field "QUALITY", until the loop is complete.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

Input = pd.read_csv('C:/PyTemp/Input.csv')

Input = pd.DataFrame(Input)

print(Input)

   QUALITY  AGE
0       15   10

AGE = Input['AGE']

QUALITY = Input['QUALITY']

loopcount = 2
i = 1

while i < loopcount:

    Input['DELTA'] = QUALITY * .1

    Input2 = pd.DataFrame(Input)

    Input2['AGE'] = Input['AGE'] + 1

    Input2['DELTA'] = Input2['QUALITY'] * .1

    Input2['QUALITY'] = Input2['QUALITY'] + Input2['DELTA']

    Input = Input.append(Input2)

    i += 1


print (Input)
```

My result:

```
   QUALITY  AGE  DELTA
0     16.5   11    1.5
0     16.5   11    1.5
```

I this is what I am after:

```
    QUALITY  AGE     DELTA
0     15      10      1.5
0   16.5      11     1.65
```

Comment: What was the input from Input.csv?

Comment: QUALITY: 15  AGE: 10

Comment: Please don't make this a chameleon question - if you still need help debugging, please post another question instead of changing this one over and over again. I rolled it back to the best original question before all the mods.

Comment: Thank you. I will do so in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Pandas Dataframe saves a reference and not a copy. So every operation is done on your `Input` and `Input2` just shows what in `Input` is set. See also [pandas.DataFrame Reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

Input = pd.DataFrame({'AGE': 10, 'QUALITY':15}, index=[0])
print(Input)
AGE = Input['AGE']
QUALITY = Input['QUALITY']
loopcount = 2
i = 1
while i < loopcount:
    Input['DELTA'] = QUALITY * .1
    Input2 = pd.DataFrame(Input, copy=True) # Here is the change
    Input2['AGE'] = Input['AGE'] + 1
    Input2['DELTA'] = Input2['QUALITY'] * .1
    Input2['QUALITY'] = Input2['QUALITY'] + Input2['DELTA']
    Input = Input.append(Input2)
    i += 1


print (Input)
```

This outputs

```
   AGE  QUALITY  DELTA
0   10     15.0    1.5
0   11     16.5    1.5
```

which is not exactly what you wanted but I'm not really sure what logic is wanted so I'm not able to alter the commands.

Comment: Thanks MSeifert and Ajean, you both have moved me forward. When I make the loop count longer, I get this result:

Comment: @ MSeifert, When I make the loop count 3, the result prints as follows.   
              AGE  QUALITY  DELTA
        0   10        15.00   1.50
        0   11        16.50   1.50
        0   11        16.50   1.50
        0   12        18.15   1.65

Comment: And that's good/bad/not intended? I think everything beyond the copy is just a question of debugging the code by yourself. See for example: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to figure out how to format the results in the comments section, and clearly need to look that up as well. The result is very nearly what I want. I'll post the result and what I am after in the body of the question.

Comment: What did you expect? At the end of the loop you add the new row and at the start of the loop you take the whole dataframe (including the last inserted row). Please read the article mentioned 2 comments earlier and if you have problems debugging or a specific question then open another question. StackOverflow is not about us debugging your program.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is due to this line in your loop:

```
Input2 = pd.DataFrame(Input)
```

You think that you are making a copy of `Input`, but instead you are making a view, so when you change the values in `Input2` you change `Input` also.  The DataFrame constructor has a `copy` keyword that defaults to False.  You can test this by looking at the underlying values

```
Input2.values.base is Input.values.base
```

If this is True, you have a view.  Change the line to

```
Input2 = pd.DataFrame(Input, copy=True)
```

Comment: Sorry haven't seen you already posted an answer with the same content. But nevertheless +1 for your answer. Even though the output is not what is *wanted* in neither of our answers.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't touch the numbers because what's coming out is exactly what's assigned, I figure the OP can change that logic themselves.